# How to create an incremental field (sequence) that is validated with a method (def)

Tags: python, odoo

i've one doubt:

I created a field called `niu` to increase its value for each product type stockable.

```
niu = fields.Char(string="NIU", compute="_niu_validation", defalut=" ", readonly=True)
```

With the attribute `compute=_ niu_validation` I call the method of the same name. In this, I want to validate that the product type is stockable type.

```
@api.depends('product_id.product_tmpl_id.type')
def _niu_validation(self):
    if 'product_id.product_tmpl_id.type' == 'product':
        niu = lambda obj, cr, uid, context: obj.pool.get('ir.sequence').get(cr, uid, 'sale.order.line')
        return super(SaleOrderLine,self)
```

On the other hand I created the render sequence for ' niu ' field in sale.order.line model.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data noupdate="1">
        <!-- Sequence for sale.order.line -->
        <record id="seq_sale_order_line" model="ir.sequence">
            <field name="name">NIU Sequence</field>
            <field name="code">sale.order.line</field>
            <field name="prefix">00</field>
            <field name="padding">3</field>
        </record>
        </data>
</openerp>
```

And in the view , I want for each product type stockable, the field 'niu' increase its value.

Image: http://en.zimagez.com/zimage/viewsequenceniu.php

Please I need help because I 've been a long time on this and I can't do it on my own. I hope your help , advice , recommendations. Thank you very much to all.

Comment: Please review your post and fix all your indentation and format it properly per the syntax highlighting support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are assigning a function(`lambda`) to `niu`:

```
niu = lambda ...
```

and you return `super()`,  `return` is not needed.

To assign a new value to `niu` field use:

```
niu = value
```

To increment its value you can use:

```
sequence = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('sale.order.line')
for rec in self:
    rec.niu = sequence
```

Use odoo official documentation (very useful), go to this [LINK](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html) and search for `Computed fields`.

**EDIT:**
Check if `niu` is already set (add `and not rec.niu` to the condition):

```
@api.depends('product_id.product_tmpl_id.type')
def _niu_validation(self):
    ir_sequence = self.env['ir.sequence']
    for rec in self:
        if rec.product_id.product_tmpl_id.type == 'product' and not rec.niu:
            rec.niu = ir_sequence.next_by_code('sale.order.line')
```

Comment: @berilios Can you tell me why you uncheck this, please?

Comment: Hello sequence works for me perfectly but the validation: product_id.product_tmpl_id.type == 'product ' does not work . Maybe it syntax error or maybe I'm not referring to stockable product type . Please can you clarify and correct me is wrong please ? Thank you.                                         PD: I did check your answer. I'm srry

Comment: In `'product_id.product_tmpl_id.type' == 'product':`, you compare two differente strings it will be always `False`.Use instead `if rec.product_id.product_tmpl_id.type == 'product'`.

Comment: Please, can you look my new answer please??

Comment: @beriliox If you want a sequence that change only for a `sale order`, you shoud reset the sequence each time you click `create` button.

Comment: What I want is that once that i create the sale order, the sequence does not change . Because ' niu ' must be a unique number identifier for each product. This can not be changed. Do you understand ?

Sorry to disturb me but this is complicated. I've spent a lot of time on this but I can not do it alone .
You look the images?

Comment: This condition works perfectly so that the sequence is not repeated. Thank you.
But I don't find solution for that every time I edit the sales order the sequence of the product is automatically changed. What I wish is that once you register the product, this has that established sequence and never change . As it is shown in the images. The sequence of the products change and I don't know why.

Comment: Can you help me with this?

Comment: @berlios suppose someone adds three products in `sale.order.line`  and save then he removes the second, what is the sequence if you add new one.

Comment: Yes, but you know ?. I realized that the ' niu ' field created in sale.order.line of sale.py file is not stored in Postgresql database when i realice someone query to sale_order_line .
So that's why I think the sequence is automatically changed. Can be?
You know why that happens ? This is my sentence field ' niu ' in sale.py.


niu = fields.Char(string="NIU", compute="_niu_validation", default=" ", readonly=True)

Answer (score 1):

You can create auto incremented field in odoo by two ways. The first on the creation of record and the other on clicking of button.

```
# on button click event
@api.one
def submit_application(self):
    if self.application_no == '/':
        sequence_id = self.env['ir.sequence'].search([('code', '=', 'your.sequence.code')])
        sequence_pool = self.env['ir.sequence']
        application_no = sequence_pool.sudo().get_id(sequence_id.id)
        self.write({'application_no': application_no})
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks WoLy you're amazing , you could solve my problem. But i've other question. What happens is that I actually generates the sequence for stockables type products . But when I press the button (save) from the header , the sequence is changed. I do not understand why this happens.
This is my method:
    niu = fields.Char(string="NIU", compute="_niu_validation", default=" ", readonly=True)

```
@api.depends('product_id.product_tmpl_id.type')
def _niu_validation(self):
    for rec in self:
        if rec.product_id.product_tmpl_id.type == 'product':
                rec.niu = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('sale.order.line')
```

LOOK THIS IMAGES PLEASE.
Sequence products before pressing the (save) button.
                    http://en.zimagez.com/zimage/4s4s4s.php

Sequence products after pressing the (save) button.
                   http://en.zimagez.com/zimage/8658946.php

If you see the images you can see that the sequence is changed. And I want the sequence is maintained.

I hope you can help me and I really appreciate it . Thank you.

Comment: It is better to make edit to your question and add this to extend it.